# Automatically Turning Wifi Off when Sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, sleep-wake

I want my Macbook to stay asleep and do nothing in sleep. It keeps waking up for all sorts of reasons and making notification sounds after midnight if I forgot to mute it after playing music.

Because of restrictions that I cannot change some system settings, I've realized that turning Wifi off is the best I can do to keep it dormant at sleep. I used the app Alfred to create a two-step workflow to first turn Wifi off and then sleep. Problem is only half-solved. Because I need to remember to always use this workflow to put my mac to sleep, and, next day, to turn wifi back on after logging in.

I can't help wondering if there is a better way to make it happen. Meaning, when I use whatever way to make my mac sleep, it turns off Wifi too, and when I wake it up, Wifi gets turned on automatically. Is there a way? Thanks

Comment: Is the Power Nap described in [this support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202824) enabled? If so, have you tried disabling it?

Comment: Hi, @Alper, no, it's disabled for both Battery and Power Adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SleepWatcher 2.2.1](https://www.bernhard-baehr.de) can do this, and for free. However, if you do not have administrator access to your Mac (and it sounds like you might not) then you might not be able to install it. Worth a shot, but just FYI that it might not work.

[Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) can do this, even without admin access, but it is not free. I think it's $35. Well worth it, IMO, because it can do 1,001 things on your Mac, and this is only 1.

I am not aware of any way to do this on macOS without using third-party apps.